# Magento 1: recommended way of preserving SEO during non-Magento migration

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, url, url-rewrite, seo

So here's the idea, one of our clients has got a Prestashop website and would like to migrate to Magento.

The migration is no big deal as we have made several migrations before.

However, I'm wondering **what would be the best plan of attack to preserve the SEO from Prestashop after migration ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below is the list of steps to follow when moving from some other platform to Magento.

1. Make sure that all your target pages preserve their URLs. Note, even if one character is changed, Google treats it as a completely different URL.
2. Export the list of meta tags from your current platform and import them to Magento. Double-check whether all the meta data for your target pages remain the same.
3. Set up the canonical tags for your product, category and CMS pages the same way it is done in your current store.

Also, if you've been using some 3d party extensions, make sure you disable the default Magento canonical tags.

4. Make sure that you tweak meta robots tag settings (especially for pages filtered by layered navigation). Check whether you've added Noindex,Follow tags for all pages that have duplicate content.
5. Check whether the robots.txt file is blocking (disallowing) Magento utility folders. If not, please block/disallow them.

(here is more info on that: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/ultimate-magento-robots-txt-file-examples/)

6. Make sure xml, html sitemaps contain all your canonical URLs and they are up to date.
7. Analyze you internal linking structure. Check whether you've transferred all cross links and they are working correctly.
8. At the next step get some 3d party tools to run the analysis of your product and category URL keys, since in Magento it may often happen that some extra digits are added at the end of URLs.

If you detect this issue, you'll have to manually fix that, or use some 3d party URL key templates.

9) Run the check of your product and category meta tags to make sure all they are unique.

If there are some duplicates in there, you need to create and apply the corresponding SEO templates to fix the issue.

10) And finally check your SEO markup - if your product and category pages don't have any martup tags, you need to add them with the help of 
some 3rd party extensions.

P.S.If you need professional assistance with moving your website SEO value from some other eCommerce platform to Magento, feel free to drop us a line at support@mageworx.com - we'll provide you with free consultancy on that.

Answer (score 1):

I would export your seo urls with each product from your old store.

When importing the products, create a csv with the new path to the product. This depends on how you import your products, but you need to have the store Id, category id and the product Id of the imported products. From there you could create a .csv file with the following columns:

store_id, id_path, request_path, target_path, options

Then you can import this into your `core_url_rewrite` table. Or you could do it directly after each product import in your import script.

[Here is a rough example](http://www.bestresponsemedia.co.uk/how-to-complete-a-mass-301-url-redirect-in-magento/) (via bestresponsemedia)

I hope this helps.

Comment: What about CMS pages and categories ? Would this method be efficient as well ?

Comment: This will work for categories and cms pages as well.